# Set of polynomial forming a basis for $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to find which of these sets formed a basis for $P_2$

I got the answer wrong and cannot answer again, but its going to drive me crazy if i don't understand what I did wrong.

So...

1. $p_1 = 1+x, p_2 = 3x+x^2,p_3 = 1+4x+x^2$
2. $p_1 = 1, p_2 = 1-5x,p_3 = x, p_4 = x^2$
3. $p_1 = 1+3x+5x^2, p_2 = 3+x$

I expanded all of them in the form $a(p_1) + b(p_2) + c(p_3)....$

After which I put them into matrix form and calculated the determinant.

For 1. The determinant was 0 and thus not linearly independent so it does not span $P_2$

For 2. The determinant was -1 and thus linearly independent so it does span $P_2$

For 3. I got a 2 x 3 matrix for which I was not sure how to proceed as I could not calculate the determinant.

Comment: How did you compute the determinants of non-square matrices?

Comment: HINT: How many elements must there be in a basis for $P_2$?